# Process tree, how to find if a said process is the root one?

Tags: c, linux, process, tree

I have a directory monitoring application which works recursively by launching new processes.

I'd like to know if I'm the "root" process in this tree. I thought about trying to get the name of the caller process and check if it's the same as `argv[0]`.

Is there a smarter way of doing this? Keep in mind, this is a Linux app.

Keep in mind, I don't have much time for this and I'm but a student, so a simple solution would be great.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Specify better what you call the root of the process tree.  It is always the process with PID 1 under Unix.

Comment: Err, the root would be the user-ran process instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `fork()` to create new processes, you can have a local variable initially set at zero that each child sets to 1 immediately after forking. Only the root process would still have it set at zero after a fork.

You could even *increase* it after each fork, which would let you know how deep in your process tree each process is.

EDIT:

If you cannot use this (e.g. because you do an `exec()` after fork), you can use any of the common ways that shells use to pass information to the programs that you launch:

- Environment variables: call `setenv()` after `fork()` but before `exec()` - or add it in the environment when calling `exec()`.
- Use a special command line argument.
- Use a special value for `argv[0]` when doing `exec()`.

Comment: Not applicable, I use a mix of exec and fork. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Have you the possibility to add an argument meaning "I'm not the root"?  That seems the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling exec, add a special argument, or environment variable called "I_AM_NOT_THE_ROOT" which the child processes get, but the parent does not.

I recently used a command-line argument for this, but env variables might be more convenient.